# broadcast receiver not working in sleep mode

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want a alarm System in my application, I want to open a dialog activity when alarm is fired,
it's working fine when phone is active, but the broadcast receiver is not working when phone is sleep or standby mode.

I also use wacklock logic in broadcast receiver but it can't work well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write service for that keep working in when phone is sleep or standby mode        [here is the link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)